# Confusing sum result

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I've 3 tables as below.

1. Users
2. StatusTable
3. Time_Tracker

And the relation is as below.

users have `username` and `userid`, StatusTable has `userName` and Time_Tracker has `userName`

Below is my table Data.

And here I'm trying to get the sum

[image]

**Problem:**

I want to update the `productiontime` as sum of `time taken[minutes]` by joining `case owner` to `username` and `TT.userId = Users.userId` and the `login = GetDate()`

My Query is

```
update Time_Tracker set ProductionTime = (select sum(ST.[time taken(minutes)])
from statustable as st inner join users as u 
on st.[case owner] = u.username
inner join Time_Tracker as TT
on u.userId = TT.userId
where cast(st.[Start Time] AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as Date)
Group By TT.UserId, u.UserId) where CAST(Login AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as Date)
```

And the blue box in my image is my current O/p.

When I run

```
select sum([time taken(minutes)]) as totalTme from StatusTable where cast([Start Time] AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as Date)
```

I get the O/p as `2.05` which is correct one.

please let me know where am I going wrong in my first query(printing 10.25) instead of `2.05`.

How can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have too many `join`s in the subquery:

```
update Time_Tracker tt
    set ProductionTime = (select sum(ST.[time taken(minutes)])
                          from statustable st inner join
                               users u 
                               on st.[case owner] = u.username
                          where u.userId = tt.userId and
                                cast(st.[Start Time] AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as Date)
                         )
    where CAST(Login AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as Date);
```

Your version is multiplying the result for each row in `TimeTracker`.  The correlation clause is what you need.

Also very important.  Such a correlated subquery should not have a `GROUP BY` clause.  The `GROUP BY` could return multiple rows, but by definition the correlated subquery should return at most one row.

Comment: Yes, right your query returning 5 times value so you can ensure it by selecting the value before updating.

Comment: Hi Friend, Thanks for this solution, this works like charm. Also I forgot to mention in my question, is there a way where I can get the session element while updating, like `where userid =session Element `

Comment: @user3872094 . . . I think you should ask a new question as a question and not in a comment.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, I've posted a new query for as you suggested. And it is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275362/update-the-result-on-click-based-on-session-id, Can you please look into it. Thanks Again